# Paypal Quantity in transaction details is wrong

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, paypal

When a user go to paypal page from my website the order appears:

```
quantity 2
price 20$
Total 40$
```

whereas in the paypal account in the transaction details what appears is:

```
quantity 1
price 40$
total 40$
```

How can i solve this problem to have quantity 2 in paypal account?
i am using  Paypal api set express check out:

```
   Dim caller As New CallerServices
        Dim profile As IAPIProfile = ProfileFactory.createSignatureAPIProfile()
        '
        '            WARNING: Do not embed plaintext credentials in your application code.
        '            Doing so is insecure and against best practices.
        '            Your API credentials must be handled securely. Please consider
        '            encrypting them for use in any production environment, and ensure
        '            that only authorized individuals may view or modify them.
        '            
        ' Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
        profile.APIUsername = AppSettings("APIUsername")
        profile.APIPassword = AppSettings("APIPassword")
        profile.APISignature = AppSettings("APISignature")
        profile.Environment = AppSettings("Environment")
        caller.APIProfile = profile
        ' Create the request object.
        Dim pp_request As New SetExpressCheckoutRequestType()
        pp_request.Version = AppSettings("APIVersion")
        ' Add request-specific fields to the request.
        ' Create the request details object.
        pp_request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = New SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType()
        pp_request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.PaymentAction = paymentAction
        pp_request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.PageStyle = color
        'Enum for PaymentAction is  PaymentActionCodeType.Sale
        pp_request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.PaymentActionSpecified = True
        pp_request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.OrderDescription = type
        pp_request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.PaymentDetails = New PaymentDetailsType()
        pp_request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.PaymentDetails.Custom = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString
        Dim items(1) As PaymentDetailsItemType
        Dim item1 As PaymentDetailsItemType = New PaymentDetailsItemType
        item1.Name = dealName
        item1.Number = OfferID
        item1.Amount = New BasicAmountType()
        item1.Amount.Value = price

        item1.Amount.currencyID = currencyCodeType
        item1.Quantity = qnt
        items(0) = item1
        pp_request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.PaymentDetails.PaymentDetailsItem = items
        pp_request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.OrderTotal = New BasicAmountType()
        pp_request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.OrderTotal.currencyID = currencyCodeType
        'Enum for currency code is  CurrencyCodeType.USD
        pp_request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.OrderTotal.Value = paymentAmount
        pp_request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.CancelURL = cancelURL
        pp_request.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.ReturnURL = returnURL
        '' Execute the API operation and obtain the response.
        Dim pp_response As New SetExpressCheckoutResponseType()
        pp_response = DirectCast(caller.[Call]("SetExpressCheckout", pp_request), SetExpressCheckoutResponseType)
        token = pp_response.Token
        resp = pp_response
        Return pp_response.Ack
    End Function
```

Comment: how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't "Dim items(1) As PaymentDetailsItemType" be Dim items(0) As PaymentDetailsItemType ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only discount option openly available for express checkout is a discount on shipping, but you could pass an item of negative value to work as a discount. I have an example below:

```
VERSION = 84.0
METHOD = SetExpressCheckout
RETURNURL = test/index.php?action=ECreturn
CANCELURL = test/index.php?action=ECcancel
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT = 0.99
PAYMENTACTION = Sale
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0 = Test
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0 = Test
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0 = 1.00
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0 =11111
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1 =1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1 = Discount item
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC1 = DIscount
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1 = -0.01
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1 =22222
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1 =1
```